# Removing prefix in numbers in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to find maximum of a price column in SQL but the prices have a $ sign in front of them, so when I do Max(column_name) it does not show me the right answer. How do I get rid of the $ sign? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some sample data please?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Rank Title Studio Worldwide Domestic / % Overseas / % Year^  
1 Avatar Fox $2,788.0 $760.5 27.3% $2,027.5 72.7% 2009^
2 Titanic Par. $2,186.8

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/c705b02114ea3db0dff0  Here is the SQL table

Comment: if you are using SQL-Server I suggest not using TEXT datatype as this datatype is grandfathered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you are using sql-server and your data is in a varchar or nvarchar column:

```
DECLARE @Data varchar(max) = '$565'

SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(@data,'$','') AS INT))
```

result:

[image]

So what you can do is:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(column_name,'$','') AS INT)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I also realised that the reason it wasn't working was because in the first row some text values were inserted which was basically the name of the columns. I removed the text row and then it worked fine even with the $ sign in there.

Comment: great also you may want to change your datatype from TEXT to VARCHAR(MAX) as TEXT is depricated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will do.

Comment: How about defining your table like so:CREATE TABLE top_movies(
  [rank] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, title TEXT
, studio TEXT
, worldwide MONEY
, domestic_money MONEY
, domestic_percent TEXT
, overseas_money MONEY
, overseas_percent TEXT
, [year] TEXT
);

Comment: you can actually use the data type MONEY to hold money values

Comment: CREATE TABLE top_movies(
  rank TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, title TEXT
, studio TEXT
, worldwide TEXT
, domestic_money TEXT
, domestic_percent TEXT
, overseas_money TEXT
, overseas_percent TEXT
, year TEXT
);
INSERT INTO top_movies(rank,title,studio,worldwide,domestic_money,domestic_percent,overseas_money,overseas_percent,year) VALUES ('Rank','Title','Studio','Worldwide','Domestic / %','Overseas / %','Year^','','');

Comment: That is the way it is. But if you see the first line the VALUES are Text. So that was causing a problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips.

Comment: looks like the first row is just headings

Comment: Done. Am new here, so still navigating. :)

Comment: thanks I'm just trying to build my profile so every bit helps :)

Comment: @Tan & @KamranFarzami: Welcome to the wonderful world of correct datatypes :-) Come on, storing columns like `year` or `percent` as `text` is just stupid, even a `VarChar` is plain wrong for numeric data and for movie titles you never need `TEXT` or `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Sorry, but those examples at github simply show the lack of data modelling knkowledge.

Comment: @dnoeth I couldn't agree with you more. Its a constant head ache. TEXT is a depricated data type. I think the previous dev was a bit on the lazy side.

Comment: @KamranFarzami: I think you didn't get the point. You shouldn't be using `VARCHAR(MAX)` for a movie title or a value like '$565'.

Comment: @haytem I think the main chunk of the solution I put forward was the SELECT MAX(CAST(REPLACE(<data param>,'$','') AS INT)) part. As for the parameter Data having the datatype Varchar and the size max is just for demonstration purposes. No one in their right mind will store a small values such as $565 in Varchar(max) its just poor design.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the amounts are all formatted the same (that is, with or without cents), then you can do:

```
select price
from t
order by len(price) desc, price desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that some databases spell `len()` as `length()`.  And some spell `fetch first 1 row only` as `limit` -- or perhaps use another method such as `top` or `rownum`.

Answer (score 0):

If the $ is the only non alpha numeric character try something like this

```
select MAX(convert(decimal(10,2),replace(price,'$','')))
```

Answer (score 0):

A rapidly alternative is this:

`SELECT column_name FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Thanks. This works. I also realised that the reason it wasn't working was because in the first row some text values were inserted which was basically the name of the columns. I removed the text row and then it worked fine even with the $ sign in there.